# How to iterate a string containing cyrillic characters?

Tags: php, string, substring, cyrillic, multibyte

I am trying to iterate a string containing cyrillic characters and perform concatenation, but my code is returning mangled text.

Here's the code:

```
$str = "слово";
$temp = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $temp.=$str[$i];
    echo $temp . '<br>';
}
echo $temp;
```

Output:

```
�<br>с<br>с�<br>сл<br>сл�<br>сло<br>сло�<br>слов<br>слов�<br>слово<br>слово
```

Desired Output:

```
с<br>сл<br>сло<br>слов<br>слово<br>слово
```

I've also tried to use `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen()` but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply use offset numbers to access multibyte characters.

You need to use `mb_strlen()` AND `mb_substr()` to isolate your desired substrings.

*note: caching `$len` is a good idea.  `mb_` functions are expensive; it is best to minimize the number of times you call them in a script.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba044ee2a43e4f78d4a6f185a847243a5d6f3fbe))

```
$str = "слово";
$temp = "";
for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($str); $i < $len; $i++) {
    $temp .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
    echo $temp . '<br>';
}
echo $temp;
```

Output:

```
с<br>сл<br>сло<br>слов<br>слово<br>слово
```

---

Depending on what your actual project needs are, here is an alternative that doesn't require a `$temp` variable:

```
$str = "слово";
for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($str); $i < $len; $i++) {
    if ($i) echo '<br>';
    echo mb_substr($str, 0, $i + 1);
}
// с<br>сл<br>сло<br>слов<br>слово
```

---

More simply, you can split the string into an array of individual letters and iterate that. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ppJor)

```
$str = "слово";
$temp = "";
foreach (mb_str_split($str) as $char) {
    $temp .= $char;
    echo $temp . '<br>';
}
echo $temp;
```

Comment: @JoeDoe I've added an alternative snippet in case you'd like to do-away with the `$temp` variable.